# JSF Deletion Confirm Dialog Showup

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```html
<p:column headerText="İşlem">
                                    <p:commandButton action="#{userBean.editUser}" value="Düzenle" styleClass="btn btn-sm btn-primary" icon="fa fa-edit" ajax="false" />

                                    <p:commandButton action="#{userBean.updateUser}" value="Güncelle" styleClass="btn btn-sm btn-primary" icon="fa fa-refresh" ajax="false" />

                                    <p:commandButton action="#{userBean.confirm}" value="Sil" styleClass="btn btn-sm btn-danger" icon="fa fa-remove" update="growl">
                                        <p:confirm message="Kullanıcıyı silmek istediğinize emin misiniz?" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
                                    </p:commandButton>

                                    <p:confirmDialog widgetVar="confirmDlg">
                                        <p:commandButton value="Evet" action="#{userBean.deleteUser(kullanici)}" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" ajax="false" />
                                        <p:commandButton value="Hayır" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" ajax="false" />
                                    </p:confirmDialog>

                                </p:column>
```

I am using Tomcat in my project and I wanted to do a deletion confirm dialog.
In my UserBean I wrote a function called confirm() to trigger it but it does not work.
I am waiting for your suggestions.

```java
public void confirm(){
        // confirm dialog show
        PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('confirmDlg').show();");
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using actions on your `p:confirmDialog` buttons?

Comment: because if user selects Evet(which means YES) I need to delete that user. Confirm dialog asks that are you sure about deleting that user.

Comment: That's normally the action of the command button which contains `p:confirm` (will only be invoked when you click "yes").